# Finding duplicates entry in excel and compare adjacent cell

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

Want to Rename Column A Name in Column B in Order of Date Of Birth as for elder Ajay 1 only if duplicate found

Comment: please format,and little more explaination needed

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should give some information where you are having troubles? You are asking us to do all the work, which is not too welcomed here

Comment: "IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,A2)>1,MATCH(A2,$A$2:$A$7,0),0)" but im getting just counts .I want to rename in next column as ascending order of duplicate @ShekharPankaj

Answer (score 1):

```
=$A1&IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)>1," "&COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1),"")
```

Comment: These formula part solved my problem but it is not renaming in increasing decressing age of person